# Why isn't overflow scrolling my table cell's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple table.

```
<table class='post-layout'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='content'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have simple CSS and want the `td.content` to be scrollable (the table is full screen, fixed position).

```
.post-layout
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.post-layout .content
{
    background-color: white;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

I don't see what I've done wrong, but when the cell contains a lot of content it doesn't show the scroll bars. When I inspect the table it's height is correct, but the height of the td is larger then the table parent. How can that be?

Here is a [sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/eeSBV/) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: A div within the td would likely fix the issue

Comment: @KevinB that's what I thought as well, but no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/eeSBV/2/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eeSBV/3/

Comment: @MathewFoscarini you have to apply the style to the `<div>`

Comment: If you don't give the div a width/height, it will just expand to fit.

Comment: if you have many tds in one single row and want them to scroll once they reach table height, you need to pass height reference through the html structure all the way through parent to last child : http://jsfiddle.net/eeSBV/6/. even then, table is not needed if inline-block or floatting elements

Comment: @GCyrillus I will need multiple scrollable columns for what I'm doing. Thanks, this will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, since comments seems to be an answer, here it goes :
if you have many tds in one single row and want them to scroll once they reach table height,

you need to pass height reference through the html structure all the way through parent to last child :

jsfiddle.net/eeSBV/6. 
even then, table is not needed if inline-block or floatting elements you need just one parent nesting childs.

```
.post-layout
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.post-layout tr,
.post-layout tbody,
.post-layout .content
}
    height:100%;
}
.post-layout .content div
{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`td` does not support overflow.

You will need to do something like this:

```html
... <td><div class="content"> Your content here </div></td> ...
```

EDIT: On second thought, why are you even doing all that?

```
<div class="post-layout"> Your content here </div>
```

CSS is what you have just without the `.content` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Put the overflow on the div

http://jsfiddle.net/eeSBV/5/

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: the important part is the height moreso than the overflow

Comment: @KevinB Is it? Because I see `position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;` provding suitable boundaries for overflow.

Comment: yea you gotta have a height

Comment: Right, but that's on the table, not the div. the div will expand regardless of the table cell's boundaries since the table cell can't overflow (which results in an expanded table as well)

Answer (score 1):

Add fixed dimensions to all of that div's parent elements:  http://jsfiddle.net/eeSBV/7/

```
.post-layout tbody, 
.post-layout tr, 
.post-layout td {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: td wont scroll unles you set it as display:block or inline-block or float. table shrinks and expand to adapt to their contents :)

Answer (score 1):

The table display types dont support scrolling you may try

```
.post-layout .content {
background-color: white;
overflow: auto;
display: block;
height: 200px;
}
```